# arabic in json not display propeplay like "u0633\u0645\u0647"

Tags: json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm working on an project that fetch the arabic news from some server that use API to send news to android application and put it to my server.

I have created JSON POST page php and that working fine with me (fetch all i news i need it) only issue with the Arabic Characters and i have add charset=UTF-8 two time as shows in below code

As a result of this code, the output something like : "u0633\u0645\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0644" since it should be something like "موقع الاخبار على مدار اليوم".

from that application the Arabic characters are displayed properly and I'm sure that they use UTF-8 as charset.

What could be the issue is?

btw i have do some changing header charset by using UTF-16 and UTF-32 instead of UTF-8 and they characters are changed as well to somrhing like Korian characters

```
$data_string = '{"para":{"pze":"2","date":"2014-06-16 13:55:17","did":"38","la":"ar","page":1,"token":"class","sub":"13"},"req":"a\/get_aet"}';
$ch = curl_init('http://NEWSWEBSITE.SOMETHING/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
print_r( $result);
```

`

Comment: that's to be expected. json will encode extended characters like that. if you did `text/plain;charset=utf-8` and then did `echo json_decode($result)`, you'd see your arabic chars as expected.

Comment: ok fix it by add json_decode     print_r(json_decode($result));